# Independence of some random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are IID. Let $Y_i = X_i - \bar{X}$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$. Is it true that $Y_1, \ldots Y_n$ are independent?

In case specificity matters, in the context I care about, $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Thanks!

Comment: I mean $\bar{X}$ is the mean of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Can you help me understand why? For some reason I've been having trouble showing this.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I haven’t been very clear. $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean $(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/n$, not the expectation $E(X_i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the distribution of the random variables, $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are not independent when $n \geq 2$ (unless $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are degenerate, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X_i = x) =1$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

To see this, note that $Y_1 + \ldots + Y_n = 0$ with probability one. It follows that $Y_n = - (Y_1+\ldots+Y_{n-1})$ is *determined* by $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n-1})$, so that $Y_n$ is certainly not independent of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n-1})$.